# How to Recursively find secondary profiles and merge into primary one

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a sample array, in which I would like to find the secondary ones and recursively check the secondary one until all secondary profiles gets unset from PHP array.
Here is the example array.

```
$testarray= array(
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def,ghi',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'uisvuiacsiodciosd',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'def',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'ghi',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcoscisudhiu',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def',
            'created_at' => '1515217453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        )
    )
);
```

What I have tried so far.

```
function duplicate_profiles_merger ($profiles_array) {
    $innderdata = array();
    foreach ($profiles_array as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val) && in_array('secondary', $val)) {
            unset($val[$key]);
            // echo 'recursion';
            duplicate_profiles_merger($profiles_array);
        } else {
            // $innderdata = $val;
//POST Request API code goes here. Like curl request.
//data '{"primary":{"email":"cool.person@company.com"}, "secondary":{"email":"cperson@gmail.com"}}'
            echo 'done';
        }
        
        return $innderdata = $val;
        
    }
}
```

But this gets me in an infinite state.
Below is the scenario that I want to achieve.

Here is the data that I need to pass through the API post request.
data '{"primary":{"email":"cool.person@company.com"}, "secondary":{"email":"cperson@gmail.com"}}'

Now I need the primary email and the secondary email for profile merge.
But there is more than one secondary profile that exists in the array, so for that, I need some kind of recursive functionality.

Thanks

Comment: _"Now I need the primary email and the secondary email for profile merge"_ can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: in_array can be a little weird: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php#106319
So I recommend to not use it here. Maybe do
if (is_array($val) and $val['profile_type'] == 'secondary)'

Comment: @ruleboy21 To run the API post request I need primary and secondary profile email addresses, If there is more than one secondary profiles array item then recursively check again until unless all secondary ones get unsets from main array.

Comment: @clash you will get the same behaviour by using in_array vs == operator.

Comment: @BilalAhmed I read the question again and now see a couple of problems. 1) I don't see a need for recursion here. None of these arrays have children you want to loop over again. 2) The first element does not have secondary, so it would break out of the loop and finish possibly. 3) You have a return statement inside the loop, ending it. What for? You just need to loop over every element and remove it when it's secondary. Remove the recursion. If you want to modify the original array use the & operator in the function parameter.

Comment: 4) you are calling the recursion with $profiles_array, but you never modify it. You unset the elements from $val, which is not a reference to a element of $profiles_array, but a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This answer sums up the comment section:

You call your recursion method with the same exact array you started with. But PHP is passing arguments as value as default, meaning you only modify the $var element, but not the $profiles_array, because of this you are creating an infinite loop.

Plus: There is no need for recursion here because there is no "child-structure" that would profit from real recursion here. A simple loop should do the trick.

```
function duplicate_profiles_merger ($profiles_array) {
    $innderdata = array();
    foreach ($profiles_array as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val) && $val['profile_type'] == 'primary') {
            array_push($innerdata, $val);
        }
    }

    return $innerdata;
}
```

This should be all there is to it. You can also modify the existing array, eg. deleting all secondary profiles. Then you have to pass the array as reference, not value: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php